# Google API Key Http referrers issue

Tags: php, google-api, google-books

I am using PHP cURL to retrieve Google book information using my Google API key, but getting ipRefererBlocked error whenever I put any http referrer. Any idea please?

**HTTP referrers**

> http://mylibrarymanager.com/*
>   https://mylibrarymanager.com/*
>   http://www.mylibrarymanager.com/*
>   https://www.mylibrarymanager.com/*
>   www.mylibrarymanager.com/*

**Code**

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9788420636641&projection=lite&maxResults=1&printType=books&key='.$myApiKey;
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$json = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Google has presumably detected you're accessing their site via a script instead of a browser, and blocked it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling the API from a server-side PHP script, you should [use a server API key](https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/credentials/key?type=SERVER_SIDE) rather than a browser API key.